# java version not recognized

Tags: java, bash, ionic-framework

I am on Windows 10 and I use Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.
I want to use `ionic build android`, but it gives me the following error:

[image: logic-error]

I actually installed JDK 1.8.0_121 and set `JAVA_HOME` and its `PATH` as following in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/"Program Files"/Java/jdk1.8.0_121
export PATH=${PATH}:/mnt/c/"Program Files"/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin
```

When I use `java -version` the following output occurs:

> openjdk version "9-internal"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)

So Bash doesn't recognize my Java version. The funny thing is, that `java.exe -version` gives the correct output:

> java version "1.8.0_121"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

I get the same (correct) output when using Windows' cmd > `java -version`.

There are no java files in `/Windows/System32` or `/syswow64`.

I think I installed the "openjdk version 9", which is displayed due to `java -version` directly via `apt install openjdk-9-jdk-headless` some day. May this causes this trouble? Because when I try `update-alternatives --config java` I get the following output: (There is no option to select jdk1.8.0_121)

[image: Output]

Or do I have to set `JAVA_HOME` and its `PATH` in a different way? Or what other solution do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

In bash, run `which java` to check which java version bash is running.

Probably it won't be 1.8, and that's because (I believe) in your `PATH`, openjdk 9 dir is before jdk 1.8.

So check your `PATH` variable (by doing `echo $PATH`) and see the order of directories.

If openjdk dir appears before jdk 1.8 (and it probably does, because you're setting 1.8 dir to be the last one), you could just set `PATH` this way:

```
export PATH=/mnt/c/"Program Files"/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin:${PATH}
```

So bash will look for `java` in jdk 1.8 dir before anywhere else.

---

If this doesn't work, you can make an alias (not an elegant solution, I admit):

```
alias java='/mnt/c/\"Program Files\"/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java'

# or without escaping double quotes (not sure which one works)
alias java='/mnt/c/"Program Files"/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java'
```

**If I remember correctly, double quotes must be escaped inside an alias. I'm not in front of a computer to test, so try with and without escaping.**

Comment: (Sorry, for double posting...)  As you said, `echo $PATH` now shows the jdk1.8 direction first. Unfortunately `java -version` again results in openjdk9. `which java` also still gives /usr/bin/java back. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I tried both of the aliases. The first one has the wrong syntax, I think. I had to add ".exe" at the end of the second one. After that `java -version` returned the correct version. Then I tried `ionic emulate android` again and it returned the same error as in my Question ("Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater"). After that, while using the alias, the `which java` command still returned `/usr/bin/java` exactely as before. This directory seems to be a part of the Subsystem of Ubuntu. Can you think of a solution for that? Or do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: I've never used ionic nor I'm an android expert, so I don't know how it checks for JDK version. Searching the web I only found people saying that reinstalling JDK and/or setting **CLASSPATH**, **PATH** and **JAVA_HOME** worked. Maybe it's a config issue on how ionic sets the JDK used or something like that (maybe it doesn't use **PATH**, I don't know). That's where I'd start checking...

Comment: Ok. Nevertheless: Thank you very much!